# Hooking to override Settings.Global.* values

Tags: android, hook, xposed

I'm using the app [DevOptsHide](https://github.com/accelforce/DevOptsHide) to make other apps think the developer mode is disabled. To summarize, we are hooking into `Settings.Global.getInt()` and `Settings.Secure.getInt()`, and override values of `Settings.Global/Secure.ADB_ENABLED` and `Settings.Global/Secure.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED` constants.

I found some points of interest, but I'm not an Android developer, and the app author isn't willing to spend much time working on the app anymore, thus I'm asking the questions here in hope to find some insights.

The originating discussion can be found on [DevOptsHide issue #17](https://github.com/accelforce/DevOptsHide/issues/17). The main code is at [HideDevOpts.kt](https://github.com/accelforce/DevOptsHide/blob/26ba6a97ee54e0c73b71ee52ce72ed6a09a80791/app/src/main/java/net/accelf/devoptshide/HideDevOpts.kt).

My questions are:

- I am right when I spotted that when hooking into `Settings.Secure.getInt()`, in the hook `param` equals `Settings.Secure.*` thus detection of access to the desired constants fails, as currently the only checked names are `Settings.Global.*`?
- I am right when I pointed out that as `handleLoadPackage()` is executed for each and every package loaded, `Settings.Global.getInt()` and `Settings.Secure.getInt()` end up with a huge stack of registered hooks?

  - But maybe there is some singleton mechanism?
  - On the other hand, if you confirm there is an issue, how could it be fixed? Could `initZygote()` be used instead (maybe it runs too soon)?

Comment: Each loaded package is an own app in an own process, so a singleton is not an option. If you want to limit the hooks to a certain app only activate the hooks if the app package name belongs to an app you want to hook. Note that handleLoadPackage is only called one time per app  process (when it is starting).

Comment: There is no whitelist of apps to hook, the intend is to hook for all apps. As you explained each app has its own environment, it should be right to add the hooks in each `handleLoadPackage()`. So my second question should be sorted out, thanks. Would you have some insights about my first question?

Comment: I don't really understand your other question. You are getting a string value. Where the constant of the same value is defined doesn't matter as you only get the value. If the constant if declared as public final then most likely it will be not read from the field on the app's dex code but copied as direct constant into the dex code. So check the value if the constant you want to check and that's it

Comment: Ah, understood. I made a confusion between the constant's name and the constant's value, which in turn points to the desired config value. [`Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ADB_ENABLED) and [`Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global#ADB_ENABLED) have the same value `"adb_enabled"`, and the same goes for [`DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED). Thanks again!